# How to get how many messages has been sent by a user

Tags: discord, discord.py

How to get how many messages have been sent by a user, I tried doing it myself but it didn't work out for me can anyone help me.
This is what I came up with:

```
@client.command(aliases =["m"])
async def messages(ctx, Discord.user=User):
    counter = 0
    async for message in channel.history():
        if message.author == client.user:
          counter += 1
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} sent {counter} messages.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user` parameter is not valid. `=` indicates default, what you want to use are `type hints` which are indicated with a `:`. This is the correct way to pass your `user` parameter: `user: discord.Member`.

```py
@client.command(aliases=["m"])
async def messages(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    counter = 0
    async for message in channel.history():
        if message.author == user:
            counter += 1
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} sent {counter} messages.')
```

Comment: No problem, please mark as answered if this has helped you :)

Comment: I will i just wanna check that it works because i didn't even,  if it didn't i still appreciate it